# Can't connect to ASP.NET Core SignalR in my simple xamarin chat app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, signalr, chat

Hey so I'm very new to ASP.NET Core SignalR and I'm having troubles figuring out how to connect to my backend in this barebones chat application I'm making.
I'm not really sure if I'm doing it right. Most documentation I've come across seem outdated.

Here's my Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Backboy.Hubs;

namespace Backboy {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the way I'm trying to connect from the app. I start with creating a HubConnection like this:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"https://localhost:44308/chatHub").Build();
```

I suspect that this line is what is wrong. But I don't what other url I should be using instead. https://localhost:44308 is what opens in my browser when I run the program.

Here's also the function I run to try to connect.

```
async void Connect(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("JoinChat", name);
                PutOnScreen(name, "Connected");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                PutOnScreen(name, "Could not connect");
            }
        }
```

The Exception I get is:

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Network subsystem is down ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network subsystem is down
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00110] in <c85119bf7e3e421490ae6b5487992fff>:0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use the IP address of your server, not "localhost"

Comment: @Jason Can't you run the hub locally by using the localhost?

Comment: probably, but using "localhost" in a mobile app will cause the device (or emulator) to attempt to connect to ITSELF, not to the PC

Comment: Yup, that was it, just had to publish it and it started working. Thanks!

Comment: You can post the solution as answer and accept it, which will help more people :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an android emulator you can't use localhost as that would try and connect to the emulator itself.

You have to use the reserved Ip Address of `http://10.0.2.2:{portNumber}/` to access your computer's localhost.